# I'm trying to make my first android App using Android Developers myfirstapp guide but i'm getting all red flags in MyActivity.jav file

Tags: android

I'm trying to make my first android App using Android Developers myfirstapp guide but i'm getting all red flags in MyActivity.java file

Now I have very little experience in Java code but I am trying to learn as I go along as I am a more practical learner so I find it very hard to learn things from just books I prefer visual references and physically doing what it is im learning to do.
any help would be appreciated

**What I did**
[image: The code]

**Errors**
[image: Errors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you either have to import `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` or `android.app.Activity`. If you want to use the ActionBarActivity then you need to [setup the support library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).

To solve your other issue you need to fix your intent like so;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
```

Because the intent expects a class so it knows to launch your DisplayMessageActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You are inheriting (if you're familiar with the principle of Inheritance) from a class i.e. ActionBarActivity with does not exist.
For a regular activity in Android, you only have to extend Activity and not ActionBarActivity.

If you've not selected an older version of the android SDK as your target, then an action bar will show just by extending Activity. So my suggestion is that you do not extend ActionBarActivity but rather Activity

Comment: Cheers for that I noticed it originally just said activity but because the tutorial said ActionBarActivity and I didn't really understand why it was different on mine to there's that has resolved most of my error's im now just receiving an error saying Cannot find symbol variable DisplayMessageActivity but with in all my other xml codes DisplayMessageActivity where needed is lit up green? any ideas.